# Problems with Modification of Inventory Program Part 4

Tags: java, programming-languages

I tried to modify my code to add GUI, not sure if I did this correctly and recieved 1 error message as follows:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\AdminUser\My Documents\InventoryPart4.java:40: invalid method declaration; return type required
public Television(String itemNumber, String televisionName, int unitsinStock, double unitPrice) {
```

^
1 error

Tool completed with exit code 1

If someone could look at my code below, tell me if I have done the modification correctly per these instructions.The GUI should display all of the items in the inventory and include the item number, the name of the product, the number of units in stock, the price of each unit, and the value of the inventory of that product. In addition, the GUI should display the value of the entire inventory, the additional attribute, and the restocking fee.  All dollar values should be displayed as currency (i.e. $D,DDD.CC).  There should not be any output in the DOS console.
I am really trying hard to grasp all of this but I am throughly confused, frustrated if I have done this right. Especially since I am not sure with how to fix the error. It would be greatly appreciated if someone could give me some input already a day late turning this in and still have 2 more parts that will be due soon.

```
enter code here
```

// Week 7 Inventory Program Part 4
//Inventory Program that stores data in Television class
// Uses GUI to return data
// With added subclass Size

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JLabel;




@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Televisions extends JFrame { //class name and attributes

    //declare class variables
    private String itemNumber; //item # of product
    private String televisionName; //product name
    public int unitsinStock; //# of units in stock
    public double unitPrice; //Price per unit

       NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);

   //class constructor

  public Television(String itemNumber, String televisionName, int unitsinStock, double unitPrice) {
      this.itemNumber = itemNumber;
      this.televisionName = televisionName;
      this.unitsinStock = unitsinStock;
      this.unitPrice = unitPrice;

}   //end constructor

   //define set and get methods for class variables
   //getter and setter methods for Television

   //item number
public String getItemNumber() { //getter for item number
    return itemNumber;
} //end getter item number

public void setItemNumber (String itemNumber) { //setter for item number
    this.itemNumber = itemNumber;
} //end setter item number

//television name
public String getTelevisionName() { //getter for product name
        return televisionName;
} //end getter television name

public void setTelevisionName (String product) { //setter for product name
    this.televisionName = televisionName;
} //end setter television name

 //available units
public double getUnitsInStock() { //getter for units in stock
        return unitsinStock;
} //end getter units in stock

public void setUnitsInStock (double units) { //setter for units in stock
    this.unitsinStock = unitsinStock;
} //end setter units in stock

 //price
public double getUnitPrice() { //getter for unit price
        return unitPrice;
} //end getter for unit price

public void setUnitPrice (double price) { //setter for unit price
    this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
} //end setter unit price


 //calculate the total inventory by returning the product of available units and price
public double calculateInventory(){
    return unitPrice * unitsinStock;
}

//toString method that outputs the class variables
public String toString () {
        return "Television Name:" + "\t" + televisionName + "\n" +
               "Item Number:" + "\t" + itemNumber + "\n" +
               "UnitsInStock:" + "\t \t" + unitsinStock + "\n" +
               "UnitPrice:" + "\t \t" + nf.format(unitPrice) + "\n" +
               "Item Total:" + "\t" + nf.format(calculateInventory());
               }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for editing this for me I greatly appreciated your assistance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is *way* too much code for anyone to read, but I can tell you that the error message is telling you that the name of the class `Televisions` doesn't match the name you used for the constructor, `Television`. These obviously have to match!

Comment: "That is *way* too much code for anyone to read.." +1.  If I could, I'd have given another +3 for the sheer dedication required to trawl through that volume of code, looking for mistakes.

Comment: Thank You for pointing out that mistake I appreciate your assistance. I apologize for the code but I am new to this and trying to get some expert input so that I have a better grasp of this programming. I do hope that if someone ever ask me for help my response will not be so sarcastic. I will make sure not to ask for help again.

Comment: Was I sarcastic? Didn't mean to be.

Comment: No not you at all. I was just looking for some desperately needed input. Which you gave me I am totally lost, not wanting anyone to do the work for me just give me a better dirrection than what I have in my course.